# Are there any Dart graphics libraries that make extensive use of hardware acceleration?

Tags: graphics, three.js, dart, hardware-acceleration

I'm creating a game in Dart and I quite like the look of Three.dart. However, I've looked at its source and I can't figure out how much hardware acceleration it uses, if at all. My game will be pretty graphically demanding. Is there any Dart graphics library that makes extensive use of hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though Spectre is still in development, it may be useful to you. Spectre is a modern graphics API which wraps WebGL and provides features on top. It only uses hardware acceleration.

Be sure to use the latest in Git: https://github.com/johnmccutchan/spectre

Answer (score 3):

Three.dart will benefit from hardware acceleration via WebGL if you use a WebGLRenderer (instead of a CanvasRenderer, as in most of the examples).  Three.dart supports a higher level scene graph including things like cubes and spheres.

However, the implementation of WebGLRenderer is not very mature yet AFAICT:
https://github.com/threeDart/three.dart/issues/65